# Bad Request (400) - Flask

Tags: flask, request, bad-request

```
<h3>Command Manager</h3>
<p>Manage which commands are available in your server.</p>
<form action={{url_for('dashboard')}} method="POST">
<input type="text" name="projectFilePath"><br>
<button type="submit" name="commandButton" class="btn btn-success btn-block" 
value="Submit1">Save</button>
```

Is the code in my dashboard.html file

```
@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@is_logged_in
def dashboard():
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = request.form.to_dict()
    print("Form", form) 
    print("The user has posted something!")        

    if request.form['prefixButton'] == 'Submit': 
        print("User has requested a prefix change!")

        return render_template('dashboard.html')

    elif request.form['commandButton'] == 'Submit1':
        print("Command button")
        return render_template('dashboard.html')
```

When clicking the first button, the code executes as it should. And I get the message "the user has requested a prefix change". However, when I click the second button, I'm constantly getting a bad request error.

Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

I can't seem to see why I am getting this - and there is not much indication of what is actually going wrong.

I also am positive it's not a KeyError as I get the following output:

```
 ('Form', {'commandButton': u'Submit1', 'projectFilePath': u'hi'})
```

EDIT:

### I had to use the same name for the buttons but with different values.

```
<button type="submit" name="commandButton" class="btn btn-success btn-block" 
value="Submit1">Save</button>

<button type="submit" name="commandButton" class="btn btn-success btn-block"    
value="Submit2">Save</button>
```

Comment: Are your buttons inside of the same <form> in the HTML?

Comment: Are you using csrf tokens??

Comment: No.
I had to use the same name for the buttons but with different values. 
    ('Form', {'commandButton': u'Submit1', 'projectFilePath': u'hi'})
Although, I thought this was getting picked up fine when printing the form.request.